# av_interleaved_write_frame(): Connection reset by peer mjpeg : What is wrong with mjpeg stream, ffserver and ffplay?

Tags: image-processing, ffmpeg, ffserver

I'm creating mjpeg stream from image files using ffmpeg and write it to ffserver's feed:

```
sudo ffmpeg -loop 1 -i fon.jpeg -vcodec mjpeg -f mjpeg http://localhost:8090/feed1.ffm

ffmpeg version 2.0 Copyright (c) 2000-2013 the FFmpeg developers
built on Aug 19 2013 23:10:58 with gcc 4.7 (Debian 4.7.2-5)
configuration: 
libavutil      52. 38.100 / 52. 38.100
libavcodec     55. 18.102 / 55. 18.102
libavformat    55. 12.100 / 55. 12.100
libavdevice    55.  3.100 / 55.  3.100
libavfilter     3. 79.101 /  3. 79.101
libswscale      2.  3.100 /  2.  3.100
libswresample   0. 17.102 /  0. 17.102
Input #0, image2, from 'fon.jpeg':
Duration: 00:00:00.04, start: 0.000000, bitrate: N/A
Stream #0:0: Video: mjpeg, yuvj420p, 1280x720 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 25 fps, 25 tbr, 25 tbn, 25 tbc
Output #0, mjpeg, to 'http://localhost:8090/feed1.ffm':
Metadata:
encoder         : Lavf55.12.100
Stream #0:0: Video: mjpeg, yuvj420p, 1280x720 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], q=2-31, 200 kb/s, 90k tbn, 25 tbc
Stream mapping:
Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (mjpeg -> mjpeg)
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
```

ffserver is configured as

```
Port 8090
RTSPPort 8594
BindAddress 0.0.0.0
MaxClients 100
MaxBandwidth 20000
NoDaemon
<Feed feed.ffm>
File /tmp/feed.ffm
FileMaxSize 3M
</Feed>
<Stream test.rtsp>
Feed feed.ffm
Format rtsp
VideoCodec mjpeg
VideoFrameRate 30
VideoBufferSize 80000
VideoBitRate 200
VideoQMin 1
VideoQMax 5
VideoSize 1280x720
PreRoll 1
Noaudio
</Stream>
<Stream test.swf>
Feed feed.ffm
Format swf
VideoCodec flv
VideoFrameRate 30
VideoBufferSize 50000
VideoBitRate 100
VideoQMin 1
VideoQMax 5
VideoSize 1280x720
PreRoll 0
Noaudio
</Stream>
```

Then I'm trying to retrieve the rtsp stream from the ffserver:

```
ffplay http://localhost:8090/test.rtsp -loglevel debug
avplay version 0.8.5-6:0.8.5-1, Copyright (c) 2003-2012 the Libav developers
built on Jan 13 2013 12:05:48 with gcc 4.7.2
configuration: --arch=amd64 --enable-pthreads --enable-runtime-cpudetect --extra-         version='6:0.8.5-1' --libdir=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu --prefix=/usr --enable-bzlib --enable-libdc1394 --enable-libdirac --enable-libfreetype --enable-frei0r --enable-gnutls --enable-libgsm --enable-libmp3lame --enable-librtmp --enable-libopencv --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libpulse --enable-libschroedinger --enable-libspeex --enable-libtheora --enable-vaapi --enable-vdpau --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-zlib --enable-gpl --enable-postproc --enable-swscale --enable-libcdio --enable-x11grab --enable-libx264 --enable-libxvid --shlibdir=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu --enable-shared --disable-static
```

avutil      configuration: --arch=amd64 --enable-pthreads --enable-runtime-cpudetect --extra-version='6:0.8.4-1' --libdir=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu --prefix=/usr --enable-bzlib --enable-libdc1394 --enable-libdirac --enable-libfreetype --enable-frei0r --enable-gnutls --enable-libgsm --enable-libmp3lame --enable-librtmp --enable-libopencv --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libpulse --enable-libschroedinger --enable-libspeex --enable-libtheora --enable-vaapi --enable-vdpau --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-zlib --enable-gpl --enable-postproc --enable-swscale --enable-libcdio --enable-x11grab --enable-libx264 --enable-libxvid --shlibdir=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu --enable-shared --disable-static
  avcodec     configuration: --arch=amd64 --enable-pthreads --enable-runtime-cpudetect --extra-version='6:0.8.4-1' --libdir=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu --prefix=/usr --enable-bzlib --enable-libdc1394 --enable-libdirac --enable-libfreetype --enable-frei0r --enable-gnutls --enable-libgsm --enable-libmp3lame --enable-librtmp --enable-libopencv --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libpulse --enable-libschroedinger --enable-libspeex --enable-libtheora --enable-vaapi --enable-vdpau --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-zlib --enable-gpl --enable-postproc --enable-swscale --enable-libcdio --enable-x11grab --enable-libx264 --enable-libxvid --shlibdir=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu --enable-shared --disable-static
  avformat    configuration: --arch=amd64 --enable-pthreads --enable-runtime-cpudetect --extra-version='6:0.8.4-1' --libdir=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu --prefix=/usr --enable-bzlib --enable-libdc1394 --enable-libdirac --enable-libfreetype --enable-frei0r --enable-gnutls --enable-libgsm --enable-libmp3lame --enable-librtmp --enable-libopencv --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libpulse --enable-libschroedinger --enable-libspeex --enable-libtheora --enable-vaapi --enable-vdpau --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-zlib --enable-gpl --enable-postproc --enable-swscale --enable-libcdio --enable-x11grab --enable-libx264 --enable-libxvid --shlibdir=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu --enable-shared --disable-static
  swscale     configuration: --arch=amd64 --enable-pthreads --enable-runtime-cpudetect --extra-version='6:0.8.4-1' --libdir=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu --prefix=/usr --enable-bzlib --enable-libdc1394 --enable-libdirac --enable-libfreetype --enable-frei0r --enable-gnutls --enable-libgsm --enable-libmp3lame --enable-librtmp --enable-libopencv --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libpulse --enable-libschroedinger --enable-libspeex --enable-libtheora --enable-vaapi --enable-vdpau --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-zlib --enable-gpl --enable-postproc --enable-swscale --enable-libcdio --enable-x11grab --enable-libx264 --enable-libxvid --shlibdir=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu --enable-shared --disable-static
  postproc    configuration: --arch=amd64 --enable-pthreads --enable-runtime-cpudetect --extra-version='6:0.8.4-1' --libdir=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu --prefix=/usr --enable-bzlib --enable-libdc1394 --enable-libdirac --enable-libfreetype --enable-frei0r --enable-gnutls --enable-libgsm --enable-libmp3lame --enable-librtmp --enable-libopencv --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libpulse --enable-libschroedinger --enable-libspeex --enable-libtheora --enable-vaapi --enable-vdpau --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-zlib --enable-gpl --enable-postproc --enable-swscale --enable-libcdio --enable-x11grab --enable-libx264 --enable-libxvid --shlibdir=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu --enable-shared --disable-static

```
 libavutil    51. 22. 1 / 51. 22. 1
 libavcodec   53. 35. 0 / 53. 35. 0
 libavformat  53. 21. 1 / 53. 21. 0
 libavdevice  53.  2. 0 / 53.  2. 0
 libavfilter   2. 15. 0 /  2. 15. 0
 libswscale    2.  1. 0 /  2.  1. 0
 libpostproc  52.  0. 0 / 52.  0. 0
 http://localhost:8090/test.rtsp: Invalid data found when processing input
```

So, what is wrong in this streaming example, if I have no problem when I substitute streams to the files?

I create a mjpeg file using the same parameters 9i.e. file is an output insteadof stream)

```
sudo ffmpeg -loop 1 -i fon.jpeg -vcodec mjpeg -f mjpeg test.mjpg
ffmpeg version 2.0 Copyright (c) 2000-2013 the FFmpeg developers
built on Aug 19 2013 23:10:58 with gcc 4.7 (Debian 4.7.2-5)
configuration: 
libavutil      52. 38.100 / 52. 38.100
libavcodec     55. 18.102 / 55. 18.102
libavformat    55. 12.100 / 55. 12.100
libavdevice    55.  3.100 / 55.  3.100
libavfilter     3. 79.101 /  3. 79.101
libswscale      2.  3.100 /  2.  3.100
libswresample   0. 17.102 /  0. 17.102
Input #0, image2, from 'fon.jpeg':
Duration: 00:00:00.04, start: 0.000000, bitrate: N/A
Stream #0:0: Video: mjpeg, yuvj420p, 1280x720 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 25 fps, 25 tbr, 25 tbn, 25 tbc
Output #0, mjpeg, to 'test.mjpg':
Metadata:
encoder         : Lavf55.12.100
Stream #0:0: Video: mjpeg, yuvj420p, 1280x720 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], q=2-31, 200 kb/s, 90k tbn, 25 tbc
Stream mapping:
Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (mjpeg -> mjpeg)
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
frame=   36 fps=0.0 q=0.0 size=     888kB time=00:00:01.36 bitrate=5349.2kbits/sframe=   78 fps= 76 q=0.0 size=    1711kB time=00:00:03.04 bitrate=4609.9kbits/sframe=  120 fps= 78 q=0.0 size=    2533kB time=00:00:04.72 bitrate=4396.9kbits/sframe=  161 fps= 79 q=0.0 size=    3336kB time=00:00:06.36 bitrate=4297.5kbits/sframe=  202 fps= 79 q=0.0 size=    4139kB       
time=00:00:08.00 bitrate=4238.8kbits/sframe=  243 fps= 79 q=0.0 size=    4943kB  
time=00:00:09.64 bitrate=4200.1kbits/sframe=  282 fps= 79 q=0.0 size=    5706kB 
time=00:00:11.20 bitrate=4173.9kbits/sframe=  321 fps= 79 q=0.0 size=    6470kB  
time=00:00:12.76 bitrate=4154.0kbits/sframe=  358 fps= 78 q=0.0 size=    7195kB 
time=00:00:14.24 bitrate=4139.2kbits/sframe=  397 fps= 68 q=0.0 size=    7959kB 
time=00:00:15.80 bitrate=4126.6kbits/s    
[1]+  Stopped sudo ffmpeg -loop 1 -i fon.jpeg -vcodec mjpeg -f mjpeg test.mjpg
```

And then I playback this mjpeg file with ffplay. The play back is correct, I see no errors or exceptions.

```
ffplay test.mjpg
avplay version 0.8.5-6:0.8.5-1, Copyright (c) 2003-2012 the Libav developers
built on Jan 13 2013 12:05:48 with gcc 4.7.2
[mjpeg @ 0x7fc3680008c0] max_analyze_duration reached
[mjpeg @ 0x7fc3680008c0] Estimating duration from bitrate, this may be inaccurate
Input #0, mjpeg, from 'test.mjpg':
Duration: N/A, bitrate: N/A
Stream #0.0: Video: mjpeg, yuvj420p, 1280x720 [PAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 25 fps, 25 tbr, 1200k tbn, 1200k tbc
[avsink @ 0x7fc360001020] auto-inserting filter 'auto-inserted scaler 0' between the filter 'src' and the filter 'out'
[scale @ 0x7fc360001700] w:1280 h:720 fmt:yuvj420p -> w:1280 h:720 fmt:yuv420p flags:0x4
27.99 A-V:  0.000 s:0.0 aq=    0KB vq=    0KB sq=    0B f=0/0   0/0
```

So, what is the configuration issue for ffserver, or may be it is a bug of the ffserver?

UPD. I have realized, that i fed file1.ffm instead of file.ffm; that caused some ffserver problem:

```
 Mon Sep  9 11:43:20 2013 [ffm @ 0x2110000]Format ffm probed with size=2048 and score=101
 Mon Sep  9 11:43:20 2013 Deleting feed file 'feed1.ffm' as stream counts differ (1 != 2)
 Mon Sep  9 11:43:20 2013 [AVIOContext @ 0x210d660]Statistics: 4096 bytes read, 0 seeks
 Mon Sep  9 11:43:20 2013 [AVIOContext @ 0x210a9a0]Statistics: 0 seeks, 1 writeouts
 Mon Sep  9 11:43:20 2013 FFserver started.
 Mon Sep  9 11:44:18 2013 File '/feed1.ffm' not found
 Mon Sep  9 11:44:18 2013 127.0.0.1 - - [POST] "/feed1.ffm HTTP/1.1" 404 149
```

After i set a correct feed, i got another exception on ffmpeg side:

```
sudo ffmpeg -loop 1 -i fon.jpeg -vcodec mjpeg -f mjpeg http://localhost:8090/feed.ffm
ffmpeg version 2.0 Copyright (c) 2000-2013 the FFmpeg developers
built on Aug 19 2013 23:10:58 with gcc 4.7 (Debian 4.7.2-5)
configuration: 
libavutil      52. 38.100 / 52. 38.100
libavcodec     55. 18.102 / 55. 18.102
libavformat    55. 12.100 / 55. 12.100
libavdevice    55.  3.100 / 55.  3.100
libavfilter     3. 79.101 /  3. 79.101
libswscale      2.  3.100 /  2.  3.100
libswresample   0. 17.102 /  0. 17.102
Input #0, image2, from 'fon.jpeg':
Duration: 00:00:00.04, start: 0.000000, bitrate: N/A
Stream #0:0: Video: mjpeg, yuvj420p, 1280x720 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 25 fps, 25 tbr, 25 tbn, 25 tbc
Output #0, mjpeg, to 'http://localhost:8090/feed.ffm':
Metadata:
encoder         : Lavf55.12.100
Stream #0:0: Video: mjpeg, yuvj420p, 1280x720 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], q=2-31, 200 kb/s, 90k tbn, 25 tbc
Stream mapping:
Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (mjpeg -> mjpeg)
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
av_interleaved_write_frame(): Connection reset by peer
```

While ffserver shows no error at all:

```
sudo ffserver -f  /etc/ffserver3.conf
ffserver version 2.0 Copyright (c) 2000-2013 the FFmpeg developers
built on Aug 19 2013 23:10:58 with gcc 4.7 (Debian 4.7.2-5)
configuration: 
libavutil      52. 38.100 / 52. 38.100
libavcodec     55. 18.102 / 55. 18.102
libavformat    55. 12.100 / 55. 12.100
libavdevice    55.  3.100 / 55.  3.100
libavfilter     3. 79.101 /  3. 79.101
libswscale      2.  3.100 /  2.  3.100
libswresample   0. 17.102 /  0. 17.102
Mon Sep  9 12:08:19 2013 FFserver started.
Mon Sep  9 12:08:40 2013 127.0.0.1 - - [POST] "/feed.ffm HTTP/1.1" 200 4096
Mon Sep  9 12:12:28 2013 127.0.0.1 - - [GET] "/ HTTP/1.1" 200 1847
```

So, what is the problem now?

Comment: Have you found a solution?

Comment: I'm pretty sure the problem is related to that "4096" you see on the POST log. I'm still tracking it down in ffserver.c. ffserver shows no error because it silently fails on most errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the short answer is: you can't do that, at least not in that way. `ffserver` decides the expected input format by looking at the feed output name. when it sees you sending the data to `feed.ffm` it assumes `ffm` data, and so when `libavformat/utils.c` routine `avformat_open_input` calls `s->iformat->read_header(s)`, it uses the `ffm_read_header` routine in `libavformat/ffmdec.c`:

```
 /* header */
 tag = avio_rl32(pb);
 if (tag == MKTAG('F', 'F', 'M', '2'))
     return ffm2_read_header(s);
 if (tag != MKTAG('F', 'F', 'M', '1')) {
     ret = AVERROR_INVALIDDATA;
     goto fail;
 }
```

here is where it sees the `<ff><d8><ff><e0>` at the beginning of the JPEG data, sees it is not equal to `FFM2` or `FFM1`, and fails with "Invalid data found when processing input", although that message is never shown.

I can't yet tell you the *right* way to do it, but at least now you know what is happening.